# Connecting Cloud SQL to GKE

Tags: networking, proxy, sql-server, sql, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to connect my cloud SQL instance to my GKE cluster. Following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine) I noticed that it requires alias IP addresses ([using VPC native](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips)) for pods to connect to Cloud SQL via private IP. My cluster wasn't setup with this IP aliasing enabled, so it looks like I have to connect via Cloud SQL Proxy (as a sidecar).

**Questions:**

1. Is this the only solution?
2. Would creating a Cloud SQL Proxy deployment/service (as opposed to a sidecar) be detrimental to connections in a significant way?"

**Notes:**
The nodes in the cluster *can* actually connect to Cloud SQL via private IP, but apparently the VPC Peering doesn't extend into pods..? :sad_panda:

Comment: How did you resolve this issue ?

Comment: I ended up moving to a new cluster with VPC native enabled.